# Calculate position of a person in an image and recalculate it on a ground plan

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, computer-vision

I need to calculate the positon of a person in a room and display it on a map of the building.

So I have a few problems to deal with.

How do I calculate the position of the person?

[Picture from a camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orsYx.jpg)

I know one point of a rectangle that is around the face and its size (Pixel).
I also know the size (Pixel) of the picture and the position of the camera (Height, where it is in the room).

With that, I need to calculate the position of the person in the picture to a ground plan of the room/building.

[Ground Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DILL5.png)

Is it possible to calculate it or need I/you more information about it?

And how do I get the position of the person on the map of the building?

I´m thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Ask yourself, "could I make an identical image appear on the camera while having someone in a different position"? The answer is yes: Someone with a smaller head, and taller, standing closer to the camera will have the same face parameters as someone with a larger head, shorter, and farther away.

How crowded is your camera? One reliable method, if it's pretty empty is to 'follow' face the down to their feet and see where their feet are on their floor. That can give you more reliable x,y coordinates.

Comment: Oh, nice for the fast replay, but who?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you reword that? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: My question is, how do I get the position of the person on the map?
I´ve only the position of the face in the picture and the position of the camera. Also, I have the size of the room and with that I need to get the positon of the person in real. I´m not that good with math. :)